# "an error has occured in the script on this page" when trying to display htm file through xaml api

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

This might be a little too specific, but whenever I run this code, I get an error.

```
private void WebBrowser_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            wb.Navigate("C:/Users/intern3/source/repos/MarketingProject/Samples/WPF/RESTToolkitTestApp/index.htm");
        }
```

wb is the name of a WebBrowser element in a XAML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=AgCKDO35_SFD68BDTuy_{my key}' async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map;
        var coords = '<%=coords%>';

       function GetMap() {

        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(55, 0)});
        
        //Create a pushpin.
        var pushpin1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter());
        map.entities.push(pushpin1);

        //Add mouse events to the pushpin.
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin1, 'click', function () { highlight('pushpinClick'); });
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin1, 'mouseover', function () { highlight('pushpinMouseover'), showinfo('address'); });
    }

    function highlight(id) {
        //Highlight the mouse event div to indicate that the event has fired.
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'LightGreen';
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'white'; }, 1000);
    }

    function showinfo(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'LightGreen';
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById(id).style.background = 'white'; }, 1000);
        document.getElementById(id).textContent = coords;
    }
    </script>
...
```

There are other div elements that display, but it's just the map that doesn't.
[image]

Comment: Tried different formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the old WPF WebBrowser control be sure to add `<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the head of your page. If you don't it will use IE6 rendering which isn't supported by Bing Maps. This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/articles/cross-platform-bing-maps-v8-apps#using-bing-maps-v8-in-winform-and-wpf-apps

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the new WebView2 control for WPF. It is based on Edge/Chromium and much faster. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf